# Call script python on pyqt button click

Tags: python, python-2.7, button, pyqt, click

I was working in two scrips. On Pyqt I create a window with some buttons. The first button is to chick and run my .py code. I mean, when I run my pyqt and I do click on my first button I want to run file1.py.
I saw some similar questions but I can do it with these information.
I have this error: `Form object has no attribute aaa`

file1.py

```
def main():
    auto = 5
    print(auto)

if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
```

My code of Pyqt is:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import file1


class Form(QDialog):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
      layout = QVBoxLayout()
      #Marketplace
      self.b1 = QPushButton("Market Places")
      self.b1.setCheckable(True)
      self.b1.clicked.connect(lambda:self.whichbtn(self.b1))
      self.b1.clicked.connect(self.btnstate)
      layout.addWidget(self.b1)
      self.setLayout(layout)

      #Inventory
      self.b2 = QPushButton("Inventory Sources")
      self.b2.setCheckable(True)
      self.b2.clicked.connect(lambda:self.whichbtn(self.b2))
      self.b2.clicked.connect(self.btnstate)
      self.b2.clicked.connect(self.aaa)
      def aaa (self):
         file1()
      layout.addWidget(self.b2)
      self.setLayout(layout)

      #Exit 
      self.b4 = QPushButton("EXIT")
      self.b4.setDefault(True)
      self.b4.clicked.connect(lambda:self.whichbtn(self.b4))
      layout.addWidget(self.b4)
      self.b4.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
      self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
      self.setWindowTitle("AOL Optimizations")

   def btnstate(self):
      if self.b1.isChecked():
         print "button pressed"
      else:
         print "button released"

   def whichbtn(self,b):
      print "clicked button "+b.text()

def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = Form()
   ex.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()`
```

Comment: `self.b2.clicked.connect(file1.main)`.

Comment: Does this work?